# php search engine addition of name search proper

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, search

here i am sharing my script which is basically related to our school database result, in script student can search their result by two type one for search by roll number and another by name for their exam result, i am facing the problem in by name search, when user input exact name then its searching from database, but if student put half of his name its not working, and when i put "like %$name% " query it will searching (like) with both roll number and Name can any body solve my problem?

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
$sclass = $_POST['sclass'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$sel=$_POST['sel'];
//echo $name;
//result_m2017
echo "Displaying Results For  " .$sel . "= " . $name ."</br>";
}
?>
<?php
//Change Table Name Here :
$tbname = "8th18a";
//if(isset($_POST['user'])){
include_once('/home/allpkres/public_html/result0/db.php');
//$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

$query="select * from $tbname where $name = '$sel' order by name asc";
$res    = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

$count  = mysqli_num_rows($res);
$page = (int) (!isset($_REQUEST['pageId']) ? 1 :$_REQUEST['pageId']);
$page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);
$recordsPerPage = 10;
$start = ($page-1) * $recordsPerPage;
$adjacents = "2";

$prev = $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;
$lastpage = ceil($count/$recordsPerPage);
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;   
$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class='pagination'>";
        if ($page > 1)
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=".($prev)."\" onClick='changePagination(".($prev).");'>&laquo; Previous&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>&laquo; Previous&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>";   
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=".($counter)."\" onClick='changePagination(".($counter).");'>$counter</a>";     

            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                for($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=".($counter)."\" onClick='changePagination(".($counter).");'>$counter</a>";     
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=".($lpm1)."\" onClick='changePagination(".($lpm1).");'>$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=".($lastpage)."\" onClick='changePagination(".($lastpage).");'>$lastpage</a>";   

           }
           elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
           {
               $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=\"1\"\" onClick='changePagination(1);'>1</a>";
               $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=\"2\"\" onClick='changePagination(2);'>2</a>";
               $pagination.= "...";
               for($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
               {
                   if($counter == $page)
                       $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                   else
                       $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=".($counter)."\" onClick='changePagination(".($counter).");'>$counter</a>";     
               }
               $pagination.= "..";
               $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=".($lpm1)."\" onClick='changePagination(".($lpm1).");'>$lpm1</a>";
               $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=".($lastpage)."\" onClick='changePagination(".($lastpage).");'>$lastpage</a>";   
           }
           else
           {
               $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=\"1\"\" onClick='changePagination(1);'>1</a>";
               $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=\"2\"\" onClick='changePagination(2);'>2</a>";
               $pagination.= "..";
               for($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
               {
                   if($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                   else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=".($counter)."\" onClick='changePagination(".($counter).");'>$counter</a>";     
               }
           }
        }
        if($page < $counter - 1)
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=".($next)."\" onClick='changePagination(".($next).");'>Next &raquo;</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>Next &raquo;</span>";

        $pagination.= "</div>";       
    }

if(isset($_POST['pageId']) && !empty($_POST['pageId']))
{
    $id=$_POST['pageId'];
}
else
{
    $id='0';
}
$query="select * from $tbname where $sel = '$name' order by name asc
limit ".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$start).",$recordsPerPage";
//echo $query;
$res    =   mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$count  =   mysqli_num_rows($res);
$HTML='';
if($count > 0)
{
    /*
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
        $post=$row['Name'];
        $link=$row['Marks'];
        $HTML.='<div>';
        $HTML.='<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank">'.$post.'</a>';
        $HTML.='</div><br/>';
    }
    */


echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Roll Number :</th>
<th>Name :</th>
<th>Father's Name :</th>
<th>School Name</th>
<th>Remarks</th>
<th>Marks</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
  {

  echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['Roll_No'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Father Name'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['School Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Desigion'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Obitained'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

echo "<a href='index.html'>Refresh Page </a>";




}
else
{
    $HTML= '<b>No Data Found</b>';
}
echo $HTML;
echo $pagination;

//}
?>
```

Comment: I think that a lot of that code is unrelated to your actual question.  Which line(s) show "query it will searching (like) with both roll number and Name"?

Comment: how to solve the problem?

Comment: i just want that my search engine will search the result by name easily for user..thanks patrick

Comment: any body here for help me ? i think its not too much difficult query :(